# How to use different shortcut to switch among 3 input modes

Tags: ibus

When I was using windows it is convenient to switch among 3 input modes, say English, Chinese, Japanese, you can use ctrl + space to switch between English and Chinese, you can use alt + shift to switch between English and Japanese or even between Chinese and Japanese, all you need to do is press once, but under ubuntu, it seems that there is no way to use different shortcut like that, you have to press super + space once to switch from English to Chinese, press super + space twice to switch from English to Japanese, that seems still tolerable, but if you add more and more input method, say switch between English, Chinese, Japanese, German, you have to press more and more time to approach whichever input modes you want, moreover, I have to check the applet icon at the right top of the desktop to see if the input mode has been switched to what I want, under Windows, when you press alt + shift, you'll know the input modes must have been switched to Japanese, no need to worry it has been switched to Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Keyboard setting -> Shortcuts -> Typing`
On the right box (probably) first option is `Switch to the next source`.
Click on this option and insert inputs you like to use for the switching language source.